# Does the addition of a second “some” change the meaning of the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, determiners, nuance

I’d like know to whether the following sentence retains its nuance and meaning with the addition of “some” before the word “others”.

“I’m good at some types of art and bad at others.”

“I’m good at some types of art and bad at some others”

Comment: Can you describe the nuance and meaning you are perceiving in your first example?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the amount of implied art types that the person could be bad at (or neither good nor bad at, if you look at it another way).

> ***“I’m good at some types of art and bad at others.”***

This sentence says that you are good at some art types and bad at either ***some of the others*** or ***all of the others***. If you said, *"I’m good at some types of art and bad at **the** others."* then that would mean that you are definitely bad at all the other types of art.

> ***“I’m good at some types of art and bad at some others”***

This sentence says that you are good at some art types and only bad at ***some of the others***, meaning there are definitely some art types that you are neither good nor bad at. This sentence feels as if there could be some importance to the art types that you are neither good nor bad at.

Comment: I don't agree. "I go to school on some days and go to work on others," does not mean that I work on all other days.

Comment: It's not so much a matter of "bad at others" meaning "all the rest" (it may mean all or some), but "some others" means "some of the rest" and definitely not all the rest. So HAL 9000's answer expresses the basic distinction.

Comment: StuartF & GArthurBrown : Both of you are correct. I've edited the answer accordingly. Thanks.